# ios- cbcentralManager state unknown and CoreBluetooth[WARNING] <CBConcreteCentralManager> is not powered on

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I am working on CoreBluetooth framework. I ran the famous `temperatureSensor` application but when i run it on simulator I get the following warning:

```
 CoreBluetooth[WARNING] <CBConcreteCentralManager: 0x713b550> is not powered on
```

and I checked the state of `CBCentralManager` it is `Unknown`. Following is the code:

```
(void) startScanningForUUIDString:(NSString *)uuidString {
    centralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];

    if ([centralManager state] == CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOff) NSLog(@"CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOff");
    if ([centralManager state] == CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn) NSLog(@"CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn");
    if ([centralManager state] == CBCentralManagerStateResetting) NSLog(@"CBCentralManagerStateResetting");
    if ([centralManager state] == CBCentralManagerStateUnauthorized) NSLog(@"CBCentralManagerStateUnauthorized");
    if ([centralManager state] == CBCentralManagerStateUnknown) NSLog(@"CBCentralManagerStateUnknown");
    if ([centralManager state] == CBCentralManagerStateUnsupported) NSLog(@"CBCentralManagerStateUnsupported");
    NSArray *uuidArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:uuidString], nil];

    NSLog(@"%@", uuidArray);
    NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey];
    [centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:uuidArray options:options];
}
```

How do I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the bluetooth device is not connected or not detected. 
You will need to connect an external USB BLE dongle to be able to use it with the simulator even though your machine might be BTLE capable.
This [application note](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2295/_index.html) from Apple might be helful

Comment: umm so if its the temperatureSensor app then the bluetooth device has to be a temperature sensor enabled with BT right?

Comment: @DennisMathews : Broken link.