# CBPeripheralManager is not powered on

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I keep getting an error saying my CBPeripheralManager is not powered on but in my code i feel that i carried this out. Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    // Start up the CBPeripheralManager
    _peripheralManager = [[CBPeripheralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];
    // Start up the CBCentralManager

    // And somewhere to store the incoming data
    _data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}

/** Required protocol method.  A full app should take care of all the possible states,
 *  but we're just waiting for  to know when the CBPeripheralManager is ready
 */
- (void)peripheralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBPeripheralManager *)peripheral {

    if (peripheral.state == CBPeripheralManagerStatePoweredOn) {

        // We're in CBPeripheralManagerStatePoweredOn state...
        NSLog(@"self.peripheralManager powered on.");

        // ... so build our service.

        // Then the service
        CBMutableService *transferService = [[CBMutableService alloc] initWithType:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:TRANSFER_SERVICE_UUID] primary:YES];

        // And add it to the peripheral manager
        [self.peripheralManager addService:transferService];
    }
}
```

Then later I call my peripheral to start advertising with an IBAction button:

```
- (IBAction)advertise:(id)sender {
    [self.peripheralManager startAdvertising:@{ CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey : @[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:TRANSFER_SERVICE_UUID]] }];
    [self.peripheralManager startAdvertising:@{ CBAdvertisementDataTxPowerLevelKey : @(YES)}];
}
```

Comment: What's the exact error?

Comment: in the debugger it says Bluetooth_RSSItest_iPad[2235:60b] CoreBluetooth[WARNING] <CBPeripheralManager: 0x16563ff0> is not powered on

Comment: It may sound stupid, but is bluetooth on in the device settings?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15354956/dose-corebluetooth-work-on-ios6-0-ios6-1-ios6-1-2

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14722092/ios-cbcentralmanager-state-unknown-and-corebluetoothwarning-cbconcretecentra?rq=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to wrap all your calls to the `CBPeripheralManager` inside a state check in order to prevent these warnings. Since you are just calling advertise at an undetermined time later, you need to ensure your peripheralManager is still powered and ready to go.

```
- (IBAction)advertise:(id)sender
{
  if(self.peripheralManager.state == CBPeripheralManagerStatePoweredOn)
  {
    //Now you can call advertise
  }
}
```

Comment: Thats great.gave me a good clue to fix my issues. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: it's always something annoying like this, or ensuring you retain an iVar or something similar - cheers :)